# Uso de atributos em C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Estou diante de uma situação onde em grande parte dos métodos da minha API necessito enviar uma requisição para uma outra API contabilizar as chamadas e assim fatura-las.

Atualmente este código está contido nestes métodos, gostaria de saber se é possível reduzir este código a um atributo deixando o código mais ou menos como abaixo:

```
[Faturavel] // Atributo que rodará um código para enviar requisição para outra API
[HttpGet] 
[Route("Teste")]
public ActionResult Get() { return Ok(); }
```

Esta lógica é possível?

Ou há outro meio mais adequado de implementar essa solução?

Tentei efetuar a implementação do atributo faturavel, mas quando o método Get() é chamado a requisição http não é enviada.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
    public class Faturavel: Attribute
    {
        public Faturavel()
        {
            using HttpClient HttpClient = new();
            using HttpRequestMessage Request = new(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://localhost:44326/teste/ok"));


            using HttpResponseMessage Response = HttpClient.Send(Request);

            if (Response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new ApplicationException("Falha ao integrar!");
        }
    }
```

Desta maneira gostaria que quando o método Get() fosse chamado, executasse o código que está na classe Faturavel, porém isso não está ocorrendo. Quando executo o projeto a classe está sendo chamada 4x e quando faço o GET nada ocorre.

Comment: não está muito clara sua pergunta... como é um custom attribute é possível programar o que quiser nele e por sua lógica lá, então a principio, sem mais detalhes, eu diria que sim

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Ricardo, vou editar a pergunta tentando deixar mais clara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você pode criar é um FilterAttribute

```
public class AutoLogAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AutoLogAttribute() : base(typeof(AutoLogActionFilterImpl))
    {

    }

    private class AutoLogActionFilterImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public AutoLogActionFilterImpl(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AutoLogAttribute>();
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // perform some business logic work
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Depois só usar na sua controller

```
[AutoLog]
public Task<IActionResult> QualquerMetodo()
```

Podes ainda usar um AuthorizationFilter

```
public class ValidationFilter : AuthorizeFilter, IActionFilter
{
    public ValidationFilter()
    {
    }

    public ValidationFilter(AuthorizationPolicy policy) : base(policy)
    {
    }

    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        
    }        
}
```

No Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddControllers(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                               .RequireAuthenticatedUser() // Ou remove se não precisa estar autenticado
                               .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new ValidationFilter(policy));
        });
    }
```

Aí basta usar o atributo `[Authorize]`

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo!